# DB index size related issue

Tags: php, database, indexing, size

I'm working in a Invoice related project, now I'm facing an issue with size of DB index or something related to `index`.

**Index:**

```
Keyname: invoice_number_company_unique
Type: BTREE
Unique: Yes 
Packed: No  
Column: invoice_number_prefix, invoice_number, company_id
Cardinality: 256, 768, 768
Collation: A, A, A
Null: Yes, Yes, No
```

Table name: `invoices`

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_number_prefix` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_number` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Invoice Total'
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `invoice_number_company_unique`
     (`invoice_number_prefix`,`invoice_number`,`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Data was inserting till: `invoice_number_company_unique = invo settings-4294967295-6`

On trying to do next invoice, where `invoice_number_company_unique = invo settings-4294967296-6`: It start showing a DB error as below:

> Duplicate entry 'invo settings-4294967295-6' for key 'invoice_number_company_unique'

I think its related to the size of index. Because when I changed `invo settings-4294967295-6` to `invo sett-4294967295-6`, It worked successfully. I have tried this directly in DB.

With: `invo settings-4294967295-6` DB Error

With: `invo sett-4294967295-6` Success

Can anyone know about this? Please try to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got the reason & answer for the issue what I'm facing & here I'm sharing that with you all.

An `INT` will always be 4 bytes no matter what length is specified.

```
TINYINT = 1 byte (8 bit)
SMALLINT = 2 bytes (16 bit)
MEDIUMINT = 3 bytes (24 bit)
INT = 4 bytes (32 bit)
BIGINT = 8 bytes (64 bit).
```

The length just specifies how many characters to display when selecting data with the mysql command line client.

**The maximum value will be `2147483647 (Signed)` or `4294967295 (Unsigned)`.**

You can see that maximum range as `4294967295`, if you look into my error, its clear that my invoice number reached that max. limit in `invoice` table where field type is `int(11)`.

I have checked it by changing the type to `bigint` & issue was fix.

Changing `int` to `bigint` is not acceptable in my project & so I has to reset invoice number to a much smaller number & that fixed the error from DB.

[A helpful note](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222191854/http://waynewhitty.ie/blog-post.php?id=19)

[Another helpful link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Glad that you made it, makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIQUE KEY `invoice_number_company_unique`
     (`invoice_number_prefix`,`invoice_number`,`company_id`)
```

Your index, as a result of the concatenation might be too big, could it be that which makes the engine think two different entries as duplicated? you can try limitting the characters token from the invoice_number_prefix and see if it works:

delete the `invoice_number_company_unique` index and create it again limiting the prefix to 10 chars like so:

```
CREATE INDEX invoice_number_company_unique ON invoices
     (invoice_number_prefix(10),invoice_number,company_id)
```

Comment: Ok.. i will check that in few hours and let you know

Comment: I have a custom option to change prefix label and so I have changed the label to `inv`. In this case also the same is error showing.

Comment: Thanks for you help & suggestion.